# Hibernate manage @ManyToMany table insertions and orders

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, arraylist, many-to-many

I have bi-directional @ManyToMany relationship between two tables:

```
@Table(name = "USERS")
public class User extends AbstractEntity {

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "USERS_GROUPS",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "GROUP_ID")})
    private List<Group> groups = new ArrayList<>();
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "GROUPS")
public class Group extends AbstractEntity {

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "groups")
    private List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

When I'm updating Users of them:

```
public User linkToGroup(User user) {
    User userPersistent;
    Group groupPersistent;

    // ....

    for (Group group : user.getGroups()) {
            groupPersistent = groupService.findById(group.getId());

                groupPersistent.getUsers().add(user);

                // Update with index for proper JSON response 
                user.getGroups().set(user.getGroups().indexOf(groupPersistent), groupPersistent);

                userPersistent.getGroups().add(group);
        }

        return userRepository.save(userPersistent);
}
```

When I'm looking into corresponding join table, the rows inserted without any order.

So when I'm sending User body and list of Groups inside it:

```
{
    [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "B"
        },
        {   
            "id": 1,
            "name": "A"
        }
    ]
}
```

And then I'm calling service which extracts data from DB and the order is not the same:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "A"
        },
        {   
            "id": 2,
            "name": "B"
        }
    ]
}
```

How I can manage the order of rows in join table?
I need to have the order of records in join table the same, as the order of the request:

```
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 |
```

I'm using Oracle DB.

Comment: Are you using JPARepository?

Comment: I'm using CrudRepository

Comment: Did you check my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `@OrderBy` annotation:

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "USERS_GROUPS",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "GROUP_ID")})
@OrderBy("id ASC") //example
private List<Group> groups = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: As I know, @OrderBy("USER_ID ASC") orders list, where the order is not materialized in the database. Instead I just can sort array before response. If I will insert B, C, A it just will sort this list, but I need to receive the response in the same order as Request was send.

Comment: I don't think is it possible. You can add additional column as something like timestamp. Why do you need this functionality?

Comment: It's required by current front-end implementation. Then I see the only solution is to add additional column in join table and sort by it.